# Calculating MTTR (Days)

Tags: security, operation

What is the correct formula to calculate MTTR in Days?

MTTR = Total # of Incident in hrs/ # of incident

or

MTTR = Total # of Incident in hrs/ # of hrs in a day

Answer (score 0):

It's the total time spent on unplanned repairs divided by the number of outages/incidents.

MTTR = hours of incident repairs / number of incidents.

> For example, if you have spent 50 hours on unplanned maintenance for an asset that has broken down eight times over the course of a year, the mean time to repair would be 6.25 hours.

**References**
[Mean Time to Repair Maintenance](https://www.fiixsoftware.com/mean-time-to-repair-maintenance/)
[Common Metrics](https://www.atlassian.com/incident-management/kpis/common-metrics)